# Space of Hermitian positive definite matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am not sure if the following questions make sense mathematically: Please help.

1) Can we define a space of N by N  Hermitian positive definite matrix with N distinct eigenvalues?

2) If 1) is possible can we define norm say sum of real part of eigenvector of the largest eigenvalue?

3) If 1) and 2) is possible is there a way to find if the space is complete?

Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: It's more convenient to talk about the space of Hermitian positive definite matrices

Comment: Great.  So now, all eigenvalues are necessarily non-negative real numbers.  That's one bit made easier.

Comment: The norm you want is now precisely the spectral norm, and the space will **not** be complete.

Comment: sorry there was a mistake. I want to have  a  norm which is quite different.

Comment: Well, maybe you should clarify a bit what exactly it is that you want.  Do you specifically want a norm that makes this space complete?

Comment: Sorry, well, I want to know if we can analyse the space with sum or real part of eigenvectors (corresponding to the largest eigenvalue) as norm. If impossible, with what kind of norm I can make this space a complete one?

Comment: The Ky-Fan norms (sum of $k$ largest singular values) give you norms from the sums of eigenvalues, as you wanted.  However, none of these norms make the set you're looking at complete under the induced topology.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to try to make this space complete under a norm?